# Excluir foto ao clicar em um link

Tags: jquery

Há algum tempo atrás, tirei uma dúvida aqui no site de [como mostrar a foto pelo campo upload](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/221047/a-foto-aparecer-ao-selecion%C3%A1-la-por-um-campo-upload). O código funciona corretamente, porém preciso que o cliente ao clicar no link **Excluir**, a foto desapareça e limpe o campo `input=file` sem refresh. Vejam:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código que tenho é esse:

```
<input type="file" name="Foto" class="form-control" id="fileUpload" placeholder="Foto">
<img id="imagem" src="#" alt="Preview da sua imagem" style="width: 130px; margin-top: 10px; display: none" class="img-thumbnail" />
<label id="excluir" style="margin-left: 50px; color: #00F; display: none">Excluir</label>
```

**JQuery**

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $("#imagem").attr('src', e.target.result);           
        }     
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);         
    }
}

$("#fileUpload").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
    $("#imagem").css("display","block");
    $("#excluir").css("display","block");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É bem simples é só adicionar a seguinte linha:

```
$("#excluir").click(function(){
    $("#fileUpload").val("");
    $("#imagem").css("display","none");
    $("#excluir").css("display","none");
});
```

Assim ele vai remover o valor do input file e esconder novamente a imagem.

Código completo:

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $("#imagem").attr('src', e.target.result);           
        }     
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);         
    }
}

$("#fileUpload").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
    $("#imagem").css("display","block");
    $("#excluir").css("display","block");
});

$("#excluir").click(function(){
    $("#fileUpload").val("");
    $("#imagem").css("display","none");
    $("#excluir").css("display","none");
});
```

Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/8xzqede5/

Comment: Perfeito. Muito obrigado Wictor Chaves.